# How does the Split feature of Ooze creatures interact with buffs or debuffs?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters

Bart the Bard is fighting against three [Black Puddings](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/black-pudding).

Bart casts [Bane](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bane) to protect himself from their attacks, which all three fail.

Bart then sends a lightning bolt through all three. Unfortunately, Black Puddings have the Split feature:

> **Split.** When a pudding that is Medium or larger is subjected to lightning or slashing damage, it splits into two new puddings if it has at least 10 hit points. Each new pudding has hit points equal to half the original pudding's, rounded down. New puddings are one size smaller than the original pudding.

They split into 6 medium-sized Black Puddings.

**Which (if any) of those 6 Black Puddings are affected by Bane?**

Comment: I've closed your question, since I felt it was a duplicate. Though if you feel it is distinct, feel free to explain why and edit that into your question as well.

Comment: @Medix2 The dupe answers satisfactorily. I didn't catch it in my own search because I was too specific in searching for other questions about black puddings in particular.